# jquery ajax request is sent BEFORE beforeSend

Tags: jquery, ajax

Has anyone had the same experiences with jQuery AJAX and the `beforeSend` property? Any advice how to fix this problem?

What I am doing is reading from a database with an AJAX call before I want to send the new data to the database via AJAX (I need to get to the last page of all comments). What happens is that `beforeSend` retrieves the data WITH the data which should be sent afterwards. Any ideas?

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST', 
    url: '_php/ajax.php',
    dataType:"json",
    async:false, 
    data:{
     action    : "addComment",
     comment_author  : comment_author_val, 
     comment_content  : comment_content_val,
     comment_parent_id :  comment_parent_id_val,
     comment_post_id  : "<?=$_REQUEST["ID"]?>"
    },

beforeSend: function() {
    //WHAT A MESS... 
    if (typeof commentOpen == "undefined") {
     $.get("_php/ajax.php", { action: "getComments", commentPage: '', ID: "<?=$_REQUEST["ID"]?>" },
      function(data){
       $('#comments > ul').html(data);
       return true;
      }
     );
    }
},
```

Comment: Actually i could write it a bit different... Like   RESET-AJAX -> Callback --> WRITE AJAX -> APPEND HTML TO DOM...
   
But i actually would like to use the beforeSend

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your data retrieval action in `beforeSend` is asynchronous, meaning `$.get()` returns immediately and then `beforeSend` returns immediately. Then the `$.ajax()` continues execution. At this point, the `$.ajax()` call is already well underway and has a headstart over the `$.get()` call. I'm not sure exactly how the two requests are handled concurrently under the covers, but that is the gist of it.

What you want to do is have `$.get()` execute *synchronously*, not asynchonously. That way `beforeSend` won't return until the data retrieval completes. To do this, merely add `async: false` to your `$.get()` parameter object.

Comment: $.get() doesnt support the async property... i replaced it with ajax() and used it there... It seems to work ;-) Don't have the time to test it more in detail but it looks promising ;-) THank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Your trying to do too much with `beforeSend`.  Your better off doing your getComments ajax call first and having it fire the addComment call.  Something like this:

```
if (typeof commentOpen == "undefined") {
    getComments({ commentPage: '', ID: "<?=$_REQUEST["ID"]?>" });
}
function getComments(data){
    data = $.extend({action : "getComments"}, data);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET', 
        url: '_php/ajax.php',
        data: data,
        success: function(data){
            $('#comments > ul').html(data);
            addComment({
                comment_author: comment_author_val, 
                comment_content: comment_content_val,
                comment_parent_id: comment_parent_id_val,
                comment_post_id: "<?=$_REQUEST["ID"]?>"
            });
        }
    });
}
function addComment(data) {
    data = $.extend({action : "addComment"}, data);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST', 
        url: '_php/ajax.php',
        dataType: "json",
        data: data
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally **load()** solved the problem ;-)

Comment: What you mean by load() solved your problem. Can you elaborate on this? Thanks.